# How to interpret lag vs current variable scatter plots

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, time-series, correlation

I'm pretty new to stats and time series, and I was following this tutorial (http://www.johnwittenauer.net/a-simple-time-series-analysis-of-the-sp-500-index/) for my time series analysis. So, I'm getting stationary time series with my first difference of data, so I'm not taking any log first difference. (See attached). I'm also creating a lag variable of lag 1440, as my data resolution is at 1 min, (transaction count of server at each minute) and hence I wanted to use data from previous day to predict next day. For that reason, I plotted scatter plot of lag 1440 vs lag 0 variable, and I can't seem to interpret the plot. It seems to me, that it is weekly co related, but can anyone confirm that?

Also, I did try pearsonr function from scipy.stats.stats and it returns (nan, 1.0), while numpy.corrcoef() returns all nan matrix.

Any help wpuld be grately appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[image: first diff & log first diff]

[image: Lag 1440 vs Lag 0]

Comment: I think this question is mostly off-topic here, because interpreting scatter plots is not about programming (this would be more suitable for [crossvalidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/). However, that you get nans could be considered a programming question. Anyway, I'll try to help with both points. **1.** The data in the scatter plot looks absolutely uncorrelated to me. You can have a value close to 0 on one day and any value on the other day, so there is hardly any prediction possible. (But a very high value on one day is unlikely to correspond to a very high value at the other day.)

Answer (score 0):

Here, I will answer the second part of your question - the one that is related to programming (concerning interpretation of the scatter plot, see my comment to the question).

**2.** The fact that you get nans in correlation is likely due to the fact that you have nans or other invalid values in the data. In fact, there is a short gap in the second time series (before the 3rd spike after the july tick). Such a gap often indicates nans.

If you have such invalid values (nan, inf, etc.) in the data they often propagate to summary statistics such as correlations.

The solution depends on the problem at hand. You can try to skip parts of the time series where values are missing, or you can try to replace them with default values (e.g. 0).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the quick reply. Well, I did do df.dropna() to remove nan values. I do have '0' values, so will that be causing an issue? This is while I try to co-relate first difference and those dont produce 'inf' values

Comment: 0-values should not cause nan in the Korrelation, unless the whole signal is 0.

Comment: No the whole signal seems perfect as you can see from plots. Can it be due to missing points? I remove time stampts which has nan or 0 values